# 範囲内の数値を順に処理する

Tags: python

for文と範囲型の値を使って、以下のような出力を行うプログラムを作成したいのですが、最後の「おやすみなさい」のところまで繰り返してしまいます。どうしてでしょうか？

```
羊が1匹
羊が2匹
羊が3匹
羊が4匹
おやすみなさい
```

コードと結果も書いておきます。

```py
for n in range(1, 5):
    print('羊が%d匹'% n)
    print('おやすみなさい')
```

結果

```
羊が1匹
おやすみなさい
羊が2匹
おやすみなさい
羊が3匹
おやすみなさい
羊が4匹
おやすみなさい
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"おやすみなさい" の出力部分もインデントによって `for` ループに含まれているのが原因です。

**修正例:**

```
for n in range(1, 5):
    print('羊が%d匹'% n)

print('おやすみなさい')
```